# Poisson summation formula for possibly discontinuous function in Apostol

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, poisson-summation-formula

In Apostol, *Mathematical Analysis*, 2nd edition, Theorem 11.24 at page 332 states that

> Let $f$ be a nonnegative function such that the integral
> $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) dx$ exists as an improper Riemann
> integral. Assume also that $f$ increases on $(-\infty, 0]$ and decreases
> on $[0, +\infty)$. Then we have $$\sum_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{f(m^-)+ f(m^+)}{2}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(t) e^{-2\pi i n t} dt $$ each series being
> absolutely convergent.

The assumption on $f$ being increasing/decreasing seems unnecessary, and is perhaps needed because the author wants to avoid using Lebesgue integration. However, I could not find a reference that states the exact conditions on $f$ for the result to be true while removing the increasing/decreasing assumption, with $f$ being possibly discontinuous at the integers. Does anyone have a reference for such a result?

Comment: I had a similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4432219/validity-of-poisson-summation-formula were you able to find what you were looking for by any chance?

Comment: Hi Johnny T.! Unfortunately not, but please do let me know if you ever find one!

Answer (score 1):

I found these papers which I post in case it could be useful to someone. It looks like $L^1$ and bounded variations is enough to get Poisson summation.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/341579126_The_Poisson_Summation_Formula_for_Functions_of_Bounded_Variation

https://link.springer.com/article/10.14232/actasm-013-518-5

Comment: Hi Johnny T., thank you very much for those links! The second paper lead me to R. M. Trigub, *A Generalization of the Euler-Maclaurin Formula*, Mathematical Notes, Vol 61, No. s 1997, which contains the result I was looking for. Indeed it seems the missing ingredient is that the function be of bounded variation.

Comment: theorem 1.1 of the first paper could be what you were looking for as well