# Validity of Poisson summation formula

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $\psi(x)$ be a smooth function with compact support. Let $f$ be a real valued function defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then the Poisson summation formula holds
$$
\sum_{x \in \mathbb{Z}^n} \psi(x) e^{2 \pi i f(x)} = \sum_{x \in \mathbb{Z}^n} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \psi(y) e^{2 \pi i f(y) - 2 \pi i x.y}  dy
$$
for suitable choice of $f$ for example if $f$ is smooth. I was wondering, does Poisson summation formula still hold if $f$ was piecewise smooth?

Furthermore, can one do most harmonic analysis with phase function with piecewise smooth function? or does it cause a serious problem in general? Any input appreciated, thank u.

A definition of piecewise smooth function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be found in the link below. What I had in mind was let $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a piecewise smooth function on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $g$ be a smooth function on $\mathbb{R}^n$. I was mostly curious about functions of the form $f = g \circ h$.

Comment: I corrected typos. does it makes sense to u now?

Comment: There is still a typo in the RHS. The Poisson summation formula is the convergence of the Fourier series of $\Phi(x)=\sum_n \phi(x+n)$ at $0$ (here $\phi(x)=\psi(x)e^{2i\pi f(x)}$). What is piecewise smooth for a function on $\Bbb{R}^n$ ?

Comment: added the missing $2 \pi i$.  by piece wise continuous I meant https://sites.math.washington.edu/~rtr/papers/rtr190-PiecewiseSmooth.pdf

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with piecewise smooth, in the question and without linking to an article

Comment: It seems to me that all occurrences of $2\pi if(x)$ in the exponent are not what you want, since the Poisson summation formula is your assertion exactly with $2\pi if(x)$'s removed. To have a highly non-trivial function in the exponent might be sensible as some sort of Fourier Integral Operator, ... is that what you truly intend? Even so, I do not know a short route to a Poisson summation analogue...

Comment: $\psi$ is a smooth function with compact support and $f$ is smooth, so $\psi(x) e^{2 \pi i f(x)}$ is in Schwartz class... am I missing something?